# Applet isn't working how it should

Tags: java, applet

So I don't know why my applet isn't working like it should, it doesn't display the links it just displays like it would if you just ran it from eclipse or such.
I'm new to this applet and I don't know HTML.
This is the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXGHTYRgjgk&list=PL27BCE863B6A864E3&index=33).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class BuckySites extends JApplet {

    private HashMap<String, URL> websiteInfo;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    private JList mainList;

//init
public void init(){
    websiteInfo = new HashMap<String, URL>();
    titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    grabHTMLInfo();
    add(new JLabel("What website do you want to visit?"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainList = new JList(titles.toArray());

    mainList.addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener(){
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                    Object object = mainList.getSelectedValue();
                    URL newDocument = websiteInfo.get(object);
                    AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();
                    browser.showDocument(newDocument);
                }
            }
    );
    add(new JScrollPane(mainList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
//get html info
private void grabHTMLInfo() {
    String title;
    String address;
    URL url;
    int counter = 0;
    title = getParameter("title"+counter);

    while(title != null){
        address = getParameter("address"+counter);
        try{
            url = new URL(address);
            websiteInfo.put(title, url);
            titles.add(title);
        }catch(MalformedURLException urlException){
            urlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        ++counter;
        title = getParameter("title"+counter);
    }
}
}
```

and the html file is

```
<html>
<body>
    <applet code="BuckySites.class" width="500" height="250">
        <param name="title0" value="utube.com">
        <param name="adress0" value="https://www.youtube.com/">
        <param name="title1" value="9gag.com">
        <param name="adress1" value="http://9gag.com/">
    </applet>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using, and is it configured to correctly run applets?

Comment: i am using firefox and i configure the java settings so that i can run applets by adding the url that i get from firefox to the java exceptions list.Before that it gave me security error.